# Smarts string for querying two N substitutions at any place along bicyclic ring

Tags: computational-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

I'm a newbie to SMARTs string representation and have been stuck on generating the structure that I want. I have a pattern of chemical scaffold of interest which I'd use as a query to screen a library. The pattern is a bicyclic ring (with a functional group attached) with single N substitution at every valid and possible location (the first row of attached fig) AND a bicyclic ring with two N substitutions at every valid/possible location. (the second row of attached fig)

[image]

I've been searching through the bottom of the Internet and couldn't figure out how to write this in SMARTS string. (since Smarts is a query language, I figured I'd do there first.

Alternative, is to generate SMILES string and run the substructure search independently. However, I haven't figure out a way to generate SMILES without me having to manually writing them down. If you have any pointers - please let me know!

Comment: Umm, you know two first ones are the same?

Comment: Hi @ Mithoron - Yes I'm aware of that.  The figure was just generated on the fly to depict what I was trying to do. Essentially I want to move N along the ring

Comment: You cannot search for a substructure without defining it exactly. Whether it is SMARTS or SMILES, you must define each substructure individually.